# What do you call the driving lane that we find in front of certain hotels and hospitals that allows people to drop off people right at the entrance?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the driving lane that we find in front of certain hotels and hospitals that allows people to drop off people right at the entrance?

[image]

The only thing I can think of is driving lane, but there has to be a specific word for it since we can see it in many hotels and hospitals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be called a [driveway](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/driveway). The Cambridge dictionary defines it as:

> a short private road that leads from a public road to a house or garage

Comment: I believe this can be the only answer. Although if you want to specify the part of the driveway that's closest to the house (as opposed to some mansions that have very long driveways from the street to the house), you'd have to use a phrase like the *front-of-house driveway* or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this called a Porte-cochère?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porte-coch%C3%A8re

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/137929)

Comment: No. A porte-cochère is a kind of porch that a vehicle can stand under, not the drive leading up to it.